# Effective Mass URL Forwarding

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm doing the migration of a site, from MovableType to WordPress. The website contain around 3500 posts and when I uploaded the information to the new version of the site, the links have been altered.

Old site link (note that the category-name and the nodenumber are not fixed values. The nodenumber is a number that change in each post):

`http://websitename.com/category-name/nodenumber/title-of-the-post`

New site link: `http://websitename.com/category-name/title-of-the-post`

My question is the following:

What would be the easiest and effective way to configure my Htaccess file to do a redirection from the old links to the new ones? There might be a simple way than to write them all by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure of the URLs is always like this, and the second part is always a number, the following should work in your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/[0-9]+/(.+) /$1/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```